# Test dependencies and testing get and setter together

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, tdd

I'm quite fresh on Unit Testing and TDD, my doubts are the moment are around the following piece of test I'm running:

```
class TypeTest extends TestCase
{
private $typeNameForTests = "staff";

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
}

public function testMake()
{
    $type = Type::make($this->typeNameForTests);

    $this->assertTrue(
        $type instanceof Type,
        "make() should return an instance of " . Type::class
    ); 

    return $type;
}

/**
*   @depends testMake
*/
public function testToString($type)
{
    $this->asserTrue(
        $type->__toString() == 'staff',
        "make() parameter should be set as the type name"
    );
}

/**
* @depends testMake
*/
public function testSetAndGetParent($type)
{
    $parent = $this->createMock(Type::class);

    $type->setParent($parent);

    $parent === $type->getParent();
}

}
```

Is it ok the way I am concatenating the two first tests?
Asserting the return of a method is necessary and makes sense on this case?

Does the test dependency (testToString) makes sense there?

And how about testing Get and Set in the same test?

I appreciate any input, as I feel like I may be overthinking some principles...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> Is it ok the way I am concatenating the two first tests? Asserting the return of a method is necessary and makes sense on this case?
>   Does the test dependency (testToString) makes sense there?

I wouldn't introduce a dependency between these two cases, as these are effectively two distinct behaviours. First method is testing the behaviour of the `make()` method that creates new instances, and the second method is testing the behaviour of casting to string.

Dependent tests should be an exception rather than a rule. Use them if there's no other way, like it's too expensive to repeat calls in each test method (think network calls in integration tests etc).

> And how about testing Get and Set in the same test?

It's fine in my opinion. You're still covering the same behaviour - once parent is set it can be accessed.

My main advice is to start focusing on covering a single behaviour per test method, rather than covering a single method. Usually there's gonna be one method call required, but not every time.

I'd update your test case to:

1. Try to name your test methods better. Describe the behaviour you expect. Start your test methods with `testIt...` or `testItShould...`
2. Instead on focusing on adding a test method for each production method, focus on describing behaviour (`testMake` vs `testMakeCreatesNewType`). This way you can have more than one test method describing behaviour of a single production method.
3. Avoid `@depends`. It's hardly ever needed and it's only good for integration tests, when you need to make as little I/O calls as possible. Unit tests should be independent.
4. Focus on readability of each test case. In this particular example, I Think the private property doesn't make things more readable.
5. Use more specific assertions for better feedback. Using the more specialised assertions like `assertInstanceOf`, `assertSame` etc gives you a better error message when a test fails and leads to less need for custom messages and effectively makes for more readable tests as well.
6. Remove useless `setUp()`. It only calls the parent which only make noise.

```php
class TypeTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testMakeCreatesNewType()
    {
        $type = Type::make('staff');

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Type::class, $type); 
    }

    public function testItCanBeCastToString()
    {
        $type = Type::make('staff');

        $this->asserSame('staff', (string) $type);
    }

    public function testItExposesTheParent()
    {
        $type = Type::make('staff');
        $parent = $this->createMock(Type::class);

        $type->setParent($parent);

        $this->assertSame($parent, $type->getParent());
    }

    public function testItReturnsNullIfParentWasNotSet()
    {
        $type = Type::make('staff');

        $this->assertNull($type->getParent());
    }
}
```

This will make for more readable, maintainable and reliable tests.